# Error when executing "npm install fibers"

Tags: node.js, fibers

OS: Windows 10
node: 16.15.1
npm: 8.11.0

When running `npm install fibers`, I get an error. The whole log is too big, but here's the part where the error starts:

```
8024 info run fibers@3.1.1 install { code: 1, signal: null }
8025 info run fibers@5.0.1 install { code: 0, signal: null }
8026 timing build:run:install:node_modules/fibers Completed in 8331ms
8027 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 14804ms
8028 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
8029 timing command:install Completed in 92753ms
8030 verbose stack Error: command failed
8030 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\[xxxxxxx]\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.15.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:63:27)
8030 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
8030 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
8030 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
8031 verbose pkgid fibers@3.1.1
8032 verbose cwd C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]
8033 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
8034 verbose node v16.15.1
8035 verbose npm  v8.11.0
8036 error code 1
8037 error path C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers
8038 error command failed
8039 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node build.js || nodejs build.js
8040 error Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
8040 error   fibers.cc
8040 error   coroutine.cc
8040 error   win_delay_load_hook.cc
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(68): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(68): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(68): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(68): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(72): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(72): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(72): error C2086: 'int uni::Handle': redefinition [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error   c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(68): note: see declaration of 'uni::Handle'
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(72): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(72): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(94): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(94): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(94): error C2086: 'int uni::Handle': redefinition [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error   c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(68): note: see declaration of 'uni::Handle'
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(94): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(94): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
8040 error c:\git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\src\fibers.cc(104): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<' [C:\Git\[xxxxxxx]\[xxxxxxx]\node_modules\wdio-sync\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
```

Feels like I need to install something on my Windows?

**Update:**

Also tried node 14.17.6 with npm 6.14.15 - unfortunately same result.

Comment: Fibers is not compatible with nodejs v16.0.0 or later, check it out here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers

Answer (score 1):

**Fibers itself says-** Fibers is not compatible with nodejs v16.0.0 or later. You can read more about it here- https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers

Comment: Thanks Gulshan. I just tried node 14.17.6 with npm 6.14.15 - unfortunately same result.